# VB.NET EXCHANGE TRANSPORT AGENT

Tags: vb.net, exchange-server-2007, exchange-transport-agents

I posted the same question using c# but didn't receive any answer, so i am going to attempt to post the same question using VB

i am trying to create a transport agent that verifies the subject line of outgoing email is not empty, if it is then it adds 'kranichs jewelers' to the subject line. If it is not empty, it propercases the format of the outgoing email

the code i have in vb:

```
Imports System

Imports System.Collections.Generic

Imports System.Text

Imports Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Transport

Imports Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Transport.Routing

Imports Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Transport.Smtp


Namespace mySubjectAgent

    NotInheritable Class myRoutingFactory

        Inherits RoutingAgentFactory

        Public Overrides Function CreateAgent(ByVal server As SmtpServer) As RoutingAgent
            Return New MyAgent
        End Function

    End Class

    Public Class MyAgent
        Inherits RoutingAgent

        Private Sub MyEndOfDataHandler(ByVal source As SubmittedMessageEventSource, ByVal e As QueuedMessageEventArgs) Handles Me.OnSubmittedMessage
            If e.MailItem.Message.Subject.Length = 0 Then
                e.MailItem.Message.Subject = "Kranichs Jewelers"
            Else
                e.MailItem.Message.Subject = StrConv(e.MailItem.Message.Subject, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
            End If
        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

the problem with the code is..
whenever i install this transport agent to the exchange server, the que freezes and no email leaves the server.

any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your code in a try/catch block and writing any errors received? When I used to write these (used to be called transport syncs) they were harder to debug than NT services (at least those crash!) Its possible that `Subject` is null when empty so you're getting a NRE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two things you can try to start out:

1. Check Chris Haas' suggestion above and either add a try/catch to deal with nulls, or specifically watch for it using something like this:

   if e.mailitem isnot nothing andalso e.mailitem.message isnot nothing andalso e.mailitem.subject isnot nothing then
   ' Fix case
   elseif e.mailitem isnot nothing andalso e.mailitem.mesasge isnot nothing then
   ' Subject isn't set, go ahead and set one.
   end if
2. Remove the code that does anything and just add some dummy code to replace it (like Dim i as integer = 2) to make sure that Exchange isn't stalling out just by having a transport agent of any kind.

Comment: i added a try catch, and switched the if case to isnot nothing etc. it now works by formating the subject to proper case, however if the subject does not contain anything it still leaves it empty. any ideas?

Comment: My If statement above will only be true if all of those properties are set. To do something if the subject is empty, you'll want to seperately test for either it being an empty string, or it being Nothing (ie: not set at all). I edited the answer to have a longer version that can do that. :)